# using a column of dates for ggplot axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, clock

I have a dataframe with a column of dates in the format yyyymm, which are of type integer. I'm using ggplot to create a time series plot with each month (there's 5 years of data) as a tic mark on the x axis. I was unable to transform the column into class date using as.Date so I used the clock package to get it into format yyyy-mm. When I use thus new column as my x axis in ggplot, it tells me I can only use the function scale_x_date with objects of class date. I looked back at the class of the column yyyy-mm and it doesn't look like it turned into class date.

Here's my code:

```
#convert service month column to date format
install.packages("clock")
library(clock)
agdata$Date=agdata%>%pull(Service.Month)%>%as.character()%>%
year_month_day_parse(format="%Y%m", precision="month")

#graph tracks different groups over time
library(scales)
agdata%>%ggplot(aes(Date))+geom_line(aes(y=column1,
color="column1"))+geom_line(aes(y=column2, color="column2"))+
scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%Y-%m"))
```

agdata is the dataframe. I want Date to be on the x axis with several lines that take the values in columns 1, 2 etc that correspond to each date.

Comment: I would recommend the `lubridate` package; the `ym` function should take care of this for you. For example `lubridate::ym("202307")` will convert "202307" to a variable of type `Date` representing July 1, 2023. In your case it should be as simple as `agdata$Date <- lubridate::ym(agdata$Service.Month)`.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Molitor's answer is right, but just to put some meat on the bones:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

# create a toy dataset
aggdata <- tibble(
    Service.Month = paste0("20220", 1:9),
    column1 = sample(1:100, 9),
    column2 = sample(25:75, 9)
)

aggdata |>
  mutate(Date = ym(Service.Month)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=column1, color="column1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=column2, color="column2")) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b-%y")
```

[image]